# Break Statement in Loops

Tags: c

What does break; do in the following code? I basically need to go out of the inner loop, but continue the outer loop

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    for(j=i;j<n;j++)
    {
        if(condition)   
        {   
          count++;
          break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: First, indent your code properly.

Comment: you could write a test program and see for yourself

Comment: it does exactly what You said

Comment: Why not get to chapter two in that book on C

Answer (score 4):

The `break` in your code will break out of the inner loop.Then the outer loop continues(if the condition in it is true) just as you want. Note that `break` has no effect on `if`s. It will break out of loops like `for`,`while` etc and when it is placed inside nested loops as the one you have,it will break out of the inner-most loop only.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as the program hits the **break** statement. It exits out from the inner **for loop** and controll reach to the end of the **inner for loop**

Here, an example

```
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    for(j=1;j<3;j++)
    {
        if(i == j)   
        {   
          break;
        }
        printf("Inside the inner for loop \t i is : %d \t j is %d \n",i,j);
    }

    printf("Outside of the for loop \t i is : %d \t j is %d \n",i,j);
}
```

Output is :

```
Inside the inner for loop    i is : 0    j is 1 
Inside the inner for loop    i is : 0    j is 2 
Outside of the for loop      i is : 0    j is 3 
Outside of the for loop      i is : 1    j is 1 
Inside the inner for loop    i is : 2    j is 1 
Outside of the for loop      i is : 2    j is 2
```